# Centering the ion-title using position:absolute

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner in Ionic Framework. Recently I have built a page with a swipe-back-button on the left of the navigation bar. This shifts the title a bit to the right: (I have added a red background to the title to illustrate this)

Not using position: absolute:

[image]

To center the title, I added the following css code:

```
ion-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 90px 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

It works:

Using position: absolute:

[image]

The problem is that the title now "covers" the swipe-back button, making it impossible to click on the button.

Any solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried giving the back button an absolute position instead? or with your current solution, have you looked into z-indexes?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `position:relative` and some `z-index` value to your back button...

I have created a working snippet to illustrate your problem

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

ion-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 90px 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button></button>
  <ion-title>About</ion-title>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know I could adjust the z like this. Thank you so much.